# How to use / include libraries in Cmake / Kdevelop

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop

I don't understand what I need to do to use a library which is located in /usr/include.

For example: I want to use the [json library](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) which is located in /usr/include/json. 
In my project 'main.cpp' I do `#include <json/json.h>`.

I don't get any errros but when I start to use the functions in the library I get undefined reference errors. I have this problem with multiple libraries, I have no idea what to do I searched on google but I only came across vague answers.

I'm pretty sure I need to do something in the CMakeLists.txt file but I have no idea what.

Comment: There are two parts to using a library in C++; the headers (telling your program what symbols are available) and the binaries (that provide those symbols). You've got the headers (so your program knows the symbols exist somewhere) but not the libraries (so it doesn't have a definition for those symbols, hence your error). You need to link in the appropriate library to resolve the errors.

Comment: Everything is written in json library readme. Just read it carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/usr/include` is accessible for include by default. But when you include an external library, you must link it to your target. In case you are using `cmake` this can be done as follows: add to your CMakeLists.txt the following line:

```
target_link_libraries(your_target_name your_library_name)
```

For example, on my machine (Fedora 21) jsoncpp package is named `jsoncpp`, and it's `include` files are in `/usr/include/jsoncpp/json`. So I create `test.cpp` like this

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    Json::Value val(42);
    Json::StyledStreamWriter sw;
    sw.write(std::cout, val);   
    return 0;
}
```

and `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_executable(test
test.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(test jsoncpp)
```

and all works well.

Comment: I did what you said and now it says: `cannot find -ljsoncpp`

My path is: `usr/include/jsoncpp/json`.

My `CmakeLists.txt`: `add_executable(cpptest main.cpp)`
`target_link_libraries(cpptest jsoncpp)`

`install(TARGETS cpptest RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)`

Comment: What system you use?

Comment: Linux Debian 8 32 bit

Comment: Is `libjsoncpp` package installed and how it is named exactly?

Comment: My bad, I copied the files from the github include to usr/include. Now I downloaded the correct package `libjsoncpp-dev` and it is working now! Thanks!

Comment: I seem to recall KDevelop had a configuration panel for the linker. Why did I need to edit CMakeList.txt manually in 2018?